# Knexjs and es6 Try/Catch causing an Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I've been working on a new application that uses PostgreSQL and Knexjs as a query builder, but have been running into an issue I'm not sure how to handle.

I have a route handler that looks like so:

```
export const getSingleUser = async(req, res) => {
  let respObj = {
    status: 'fail',
    message: 'User does not exist'
  };

  try {
    const user = await knex('users').where('id', req.params.id).first();
    if (!user) {
      res.send(respObj);
    }
    respObj = {
      status: 'success',
      data: user
    };
    res.send(respObj);
  } catch(e) {
    res.send(respObj);
  }
};
```

It works great, until I throw a non-existent user ID into the mix. I assumed the catch statement would handle the error if no user is found for the query, but that doesn't seem to work, it just spits out the `respObj` in the try block. So I added an if statement to check if the user object doesn't exist, and thats when I received the warning below:

```
(node:25711) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:503:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:510:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (/Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at _callee3$ (/Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/src/controllers/userController.js:45:7)
    at tryCatch (/Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
    at step (/Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/src/controllers/userController.js:14:191)
    at /Users/munsterberg/Sites/fullstack_workspace/esports-manager/services/project/src/controllers/userController.js:14:361
    at <anonymous>
(node:25711) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25711) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Can anyone provide more info on why this is happening, and whats the fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Work around**

A response is sent twice in the `try` block if the user does not exist. This accounts for the error raised:

> "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".

The unhandled promise rejection warning is being raised because if the `res.send()` call in the `catch` code block throws, the promise returned from calling `getSingleUser` gets rejected with the same error - implying there is no error handling in place for the returned promise (because isn't supposed to get rejected).

Directing the "user does not exist" case to the catch block, by throwing an error, could be a work around to avoid the issue in the first place. A cut-down example:

```
export const getSingleUser = async(req, res) => {
  try  {
    const user = await knex('users').where('id', req.params.id).first();
    if (!user) {
      throw new Error(" user does not exist");
    }
    res.send( {
      status: 'success',
      data: user
    });
  } catch(e) {
    // console.log(e);  // debug if needed
    res.send( {
      status: 'fail',
      message: 'User does not exist'
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Perfect explanation. My lack of knowledge on the try/catch block is what the problem was. Thank you so much :)